# How to execute js code after an async script has altered the dom?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm loading an async script that alters the dom. If I add an `onload` to the script, I can run code after the script has been loaded. However, the dom has still not been edited by the script. Is there a way to wait until the dom edits have been completed before running my code?

Simple Example:

```
<script>
  function onLoad() {
    // this logs null, but it should return a div
    console.log('loaded', document.getElementById('asdf'));
  }

  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text\/javascript";
  s.onload = onLoad
  s.src = "some script that adds a div with id of asdf";
  document.head.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', s);
</script>
```

Comment: add a callback to that script...

Comment: To expand on what Jonas w is saying, that async script should expose an api for other scripts to interact with

Comment: you can use `addEventListener` to wait until a specific element is loaded and then have it run the script

Comment: You are calling `onLoad` immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [functions and when to use brackets/parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867392/functions-and-when-to-use-brackets-parenthesis)

Comment: Even without calling onLoad() immediately, it still does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the async script does not allow me to provide a callback.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are calling `onLoad()` immediately. Remove `()` to reference function `onLoad`, instead of calling the function.

```html
<div id="asdf">asdf</div>
<script>
  function onLoad() {
    // this logs null, but it should return a div
    console.log('loaded', document.getElementById('asdf'));
  }

  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.onload = onLoad;
  s.src = "data:text/javascript,console.log('script src')";
  document.head.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', s);
</script>
```

Comment: It still logs null to the console rather than the div element.

Comment: @Daniel Can you create a plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `addEventListener` to wait until the element has loaded and then have it run the script.

```js
 function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("load",function(e){
     if(e.target.id == 'asdf'){
      console.log('loaded', document.getElementById('asdf'));
        }
     });
  }
```